# Where does python output go in the game engine?

Tags: python, game-engine

I've been messing around with the game engine for a bit and decided to do some testing with python. What I have set up is a logic brick that executes a python script every time I press "W". The script should then print out a line.

What I don't understand is where the script's output goes. I don't see anything in the console or anywhere else. Does it output at all? Do you need a special bge function to print lines into the console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simple. Go to **Window** > **Toggle System Console**

[image]

**Result:**
[image]